# What does this symbol "<<<HTML" mean?

Tags: php, html

While reading code of another programmer, I have encountered `<<<H.TML` symbol. My colleagues said that it is used to write html within a php file.

I tried to find more details about its usage but I didn't find much. Please anyone explain to me how it works and what does it called?

```
    public function SetContent($page = '') {

    $this->_header->SetPageNavigation($page) ;
    $budgetHTML = '';

    $signup1 = '';
         $GetHeader =  $this->_header->GetHeader() ;
         $GetFooter =  $this->_footer->GetFooter() ;

    $DocType = <<<HTML

<!DOCTYPE html>

<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<!--[if IE 9]>    <html class="no-js ie9 ie" lang="en"> <![endif]-->

<!--[if gt IE 9]><![endif]-->

HTML;
         $this->_html = sprintf("{$DocType}<html>");
        $this->_html .= sprintf("%s", $this->_head->GetHTML());
        $bg=$this->_common->getBgImage();
         $bg=json_decode($bg);

    if(!empty($bg->BGImage)&&(file_exists($GLOBALS['DocumentRoot'].'/bgImages/'.$bg->BGImage)))
    {
        $backgroundImage='background: url('.$GLOBALS['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bgImages/'.$bg->BGImage.') no-repeat fixed top center;background-size: cover !important;';
    }
    else
    {
        $backgroundImage='';
    }
   $this->_html .= sprintf( '<body style="'.$backgroundImage.'" >

         <noscript>

            <h1 style="color:red; text-align:center; padding-top:100px;">This page needs JavaScript activated to work</h1>

            <style>div { display:none; }</style>

        </noscript>
<div class="loading"><img src="'.$GLOBALS['RootURL'].'images/main-loader.GIF" width="128" height="128"  ></div>
        <div id="wrapper"><div class="page-bg">%s%s%s%s<div class="clear"></div></div></div>', $GetHeader, $budgetHTML, $this->_maincontenthtml, $GetFooter);

    $this->_html .= sprintf("</body>");
}
```

Comment: Where did you find this code? Is it available in an open source repository whose link you can share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking at is called [heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

It's used to declare a long string literal when you don't want to use quotes.  From the PHP documentation:

```
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

In your case, they're using `HTML` for that symbol instead of `EOD`.  It actually has nothing to do with HTML at all, but you could assign a large block of HTML to a variable if you wanted to, just like any other string literal value.

Comment: Basically, its like xml tags. we can name them the way we like, right?

Comment: @NuttyProgrammer From the documentation:  "Also, the identifier must follow the same naming rules as any other label in PHP: it must contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores, and must start with a non-digit character or underscore."

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's using in PHP syntax when you want to use big content as string in PHP variable then you can use [`heredoc syntax`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax

Example:

```
<?php
$str = <<<EOD
Example of string
spanning multiple lines
using heredoc syntax.
EOD;
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a heredoc.it's allow people to easily write large amounts of text from within PHP, but without the need to constantly escape things.Heredoc's are a great alternative to quoted strings because of increased readability and maintainability. You don't have to escape quotes and (good) IDE's or text editors will use the proper syntax highlighting.

A VERY common example: echoing out HTML from within PHP:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div class='something'>
<ul class='mylist'>
  <li>$something</li>
  <li>$whatever</li>
  <li>$testing123</li>
</ul>
</div>
HTML;
// sometime later
echo $html;
```

[Also prefer](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/2/6/3)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I also feel that it really increases the code readability.

Comment: @NuttyProgrammer ok whenever your reputation become 15 or more,upvote my answer :)